# iis7 serving .php file

Tags: php, iis-7

I have a old php applications which was earlier hosted on Apache 2.2. Now I am trying to host it on IIS 7.5. I installed php with WebPlatform installer. Then copied directory to inetpub\wwwroot folder. Added this directory as application in IIS. But when I browse search.php, it pops up save as file dialog in the browser - asking to save the file. Instead should return the html response which browser can show.

If put sample index.php with phpInfo() in it. It works properly but not the acutal PHP files. Have I missed any steps?

Any php guys out there? I tried reinstalling, even with xampp, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You have installed it but might not be configured properly. You should follow instructions over [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/04/04/howto-install-and-run-php-on-iis7.aspx)